# Do I really need firebase admin sdk to determine roles of user and admin?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Do I really need firebase admin sdk to determine roles of user and admin or can I still do it with roles as a field with a datatype of an array and based on that I'll determine if the user is just a regular user or an admin?

Comment: it is just an extra layer of security, if you want to verify user

Comment: @webcoder what if I'd there's a function to add an admin?

Comment: @webcoder The Admin SDK goes WAY beyond adding an extra layer of security. It gives the developer the ability to add users for example; something that cannot be done at the client level. It also allows for user lists, deleting, updating emails etc. For the OP: Firebase does not have *user roles*, only Users. User roles are something YOU define within the scope of your app and database. If you need the functions I just mentioned, then yes you do. However the question is super broad and no way for us to provide an specific answer without understanding the entire use case.

Comment: It's like the admin can add more admins and the admin can also add staff members.

Comment: I understand the question but that's not how firebase works. There is no 'admin', there are only *users* and your app code and structure (and security rules) defines what a user can do. You could just as easily call a user with additional capabilities the 'emperor' or the 'king of the world'. The big picture is that you define in code which users(s) have additional capabilities - but they are still just a user. So yes, if a user can interact with the Admin SDK, they can create, modify and delete other users. If you don't need that capability, then no, you don't need the Admin SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well base your user roles based access rights strategy on Firestore documents and not on Custom Claims. In this case you don't need the Admin SDK. You have to take care, however, that your security rules correctly protect the collections/docs where the access rights are declared!

You will find some examples in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#access_other_documents) as well as in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-firestore-security-rules-based-on-user-groups-defined-in-firestore-documents-824c8be76795) (for user groups).